# How to deserialize a specific json subtree from a larger json payload?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

Can someone tell me how to get the value from the Time_off_type ID?
I use a Serializer to make objects from the json string. I used a website to generate de class.

```
{
  "success": true,
  "metadata": {
    "total_elements": 4,
    "current_page": 1,
    "total_pages": 1
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "TimeOffPeriod",
      "attributes": {
        "id": 163758516,
        "status": "approved",
        "comment": "",
        "start_date": "2022-12-02T00:00:00+01:00",
        "end_date": "2022-12-02T00:00:00+01:00",
        "days_count": 1,
        "half_day_start": 0,
        "half_day_end": 0,
        "time_off_type": {
          "type": "TimeOffType",
          "attributes": {
            "id": **434601**,
            "name": "Krankheit",
            "category": "sick_leave"
          }
        },
        "employee": {
          "type": "Employee",
          "attributes": {
            "id": {
              "label": "ID",
              "value": ,
              "type": "integer",
              "universal_id": "id"
            },
            "first_name": {
              "label": "First name",
              "value": "",
              "type": "standard",
              "universal_id": "first_name"
            },
            "last_name": {
              "label": "Last name",
              "value": "",
              "type": "standard",
              "universal_id": "last_name"
            },
            "email": {
              "label": "Email",
              "value": "",
              "type": "standard",
              "universal_id": "email"
            }
          }
        },
        "created_by": "",
        "certificate": {
          "status": "approved"
        },
        "created_at": "2022-12-02T11:01:58+01:00",
        "updated_at": "2022-12-02T11:02:05+01:00"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I marked the part i need. I used something like this in my code.

```
Time_off_type abwId = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Time_off_type>(result);

x.Id = abwId.attributes.Id;
```

But everytime my abwId is null even when i get a valid json example.
Would appriciate the help im now 3h in.

Comment: It's null probably because your `Time_off_type` describes only the 'time_off_type' part of the response, and the `result` variable probably holds the whole response. You have to (somehow) parse the WHOLE response, and then cut out only that inner fragment, and the deserialize just that fragment -- that's what Naeem's answer does. Or you can prepare model (full, or at least partial) for whole response, and then `.Deserialize<ResponseModel>(result)` and then dig in obtained ResponseModel to get the part you want.

Answer (score 0):

please use

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

string getPropFromJson(string json)
{
   JObject jsonToJObject=JObject.Parse(json);
   
   var tot= jsonToJObject.Value<Time_off_type>("data[0].attributes.time_off_type");

}
```

Comment: That doesnt work it returns null with the same input as my post here. Sry.

Comment: I don't know what your class looks like. But have you taken into account that the data property is an Array? You might have to reference it by using data[0] and then .attributes.time_off_type.attributes.id

Comment: at least `.attributes` is still missing in the value path before `time_off_type`